# Fragment don't respect screenOrientation="user"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity with just a FrameLayout, and there, a Fragment. This Fragment fills the entire screen.
When the user disable Auto Rotate on his device, only Activities work as well. In the scenario above don't. Still rotate my Activity with Fragment inside.
I put this `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);` on the Fragment. With this approach the Activity does not rotate, but the `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` still called and recreating my Activity.
If the user disable Auto Rotate on his device, the Activity should not be recreated. Am i wrong?

All my Activities has `screenOrientation="user"` on AndroidManifest, even so, still does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must add that code(setRequestedOrientation) while creating the activity (In onCreate method of activity)
and the second option is adding it in the androidManifest file.

Rest of you thought on it is correct.
For more info: [activity-elements search for screenOrientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Hi. So, i already did this. With config on Manifest, with config on Java class and both. The weird is: In my DealActivity, it works perfectly. But, in my LeadDealershipActivity still recreating the Activity. In the manifest, DealActivity has <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" > for deep link. Can you suggest anything else?